# Dúvida em query no SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Preciso que nessa consulta venha somente os registros em que a coluna CURVA ABC seja diferente da coluna MODELO.

Por exemplo, esse cliente a curva ABC dele é prata e o modelo é diamante/ouro, então, percebe-se que o nome prata não encontra-se no campo modelo.

```
SELECT 
C.UsuID [Código],
    U.UsuNome [Cliente],
    P.ProNome [Produto],
    M.MCDescricao [Modelo],
    M.MCId [ID_Modelo],
    A.Descricao [Curva ABC],
    A.CurvaID [ID_Curva]
FROM Usuario U 
INNER JOIN ParametroProdutoCliente PPC ON U.UsuID = PPC.UsuID
INNER JOIN ComplementoColunas C ON U.UsuID = C.UsuID AND C.LinhaID  = 1 
                                                     AND C.CompID       = 32 
                                                     AND C.ColunaID = 12
LEFT JOIN  CurvaABC     A     ON A.CurvaID = U.CurvaID
INNER JOIN Usuario            AU ON AU.UsuID = c.ColunaValor
JOIN ProdutoUsuario PU ON U.UsuID = PU.UsuID
    JOIN Produto P ON PU.ProID = P.ProID
    JOIN ModeloCriticidade M ON PU.MCId = M.MCId AND PU.ProID = M.ProID
WHERE U.EmpLiberada = 1 AND U.UsuTipo = 'C' AND PPC.ProID in(2,5,12)
AND U.UsuID = 316
```

O resultado é dessa maneira:

```
Cliente           Produto             Modelo     ID_Modelo  Curva ABC
ChilliBeans Conciliador e-Extrato   Diamante|Ouro   23       PRATA
```

Comment: `Where CurvaABC <> Modelo`?

Comment: Seria mais como se fosse um like. Na coluna Curva ABC, tem o nome prata, porém, esse nome prata nao está na coluna modelo. Entendeu?

Comment: Not exists https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms184297(v=sql.105).aspx , creio que resolva

Comment: Comparações usando cadeia de caracteres podem não ser práticas. Por acaso não existe forma de estabelecer correspondência entre as tabelas `CurvaABC` e `ModeloCriticidade`, usando as colunas `CurvaID` e `McID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo o que entendi, você deseja obter os registros cujo valor da coluna CURVA ABC **não esteja contido** na coluna MODELO

Para isso, basta utilizar uma das seguintes condições:

Opção 1: `CHARINDEX(CurvaABC.Descricao,ModeloCriticidade.MCDescricao) = 0`

Opção 2: `NOT ModeloCriticidade.MCDescricao LIKE '%' + CurvaABC.Descricao + '%'`

Caso deseje que a query retorne os registros que não tenham correspondência na tabela CurvaABC (`Descricao IS NULL`), acrescente nas opções acima a função `ISNULL(CurvaABC.Descricao,'xxx')`

A query poderia ficar assim:

```
SELECT 
    C.UsuID [Código],
    U.UsuNome [Cliente],
    P.ProNome [Produto],
    M.MCDescricao [Modelo],
    M.MCId [ID_Modelo],
    A.Descricao [Curva ABC],
    A.CurvaID [ID_Curva]
FROM Usuario U 
JOIN ParametroProdutoCliente PPC ON U.UsuID = PPC.UsuID
JOIN ComplementoColunas C ON U.UsuID = C.UsuID A
                             AND C.LinhaID = 1 
                             AND C.CompID = 32 
                             AND C.ColunaID = 12
JOIN Usuario AU ON AU.UsuID = c.ColunaValor
JOIN ProdutoUsuario PU ON U.UsuID = PU.UsuID
JOIN Produto P ON PU.ProID = P.ProID
JOIN ModeloCriticidade M ON PU.MCId = M.MCId AND PU.ProID = M.ProID
LEFT JOIN CurvaABC A  ON A.CurvaID = U.CurvaID
WHERE U.EmpLiberada = 1 
      AND U.UsuTipo = 'C' 
      AND PPC.ProID in(2,5,12)
      AND CHARINDEX( ISNULL(A.Descricao,'xxx') , M.MCDescricao ) = 0
```

Comment: isso mesmo @Fernando, obrigadão cara